# Div position not so absolute

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

Ok I have read through a huge portion of all the issues with div and absolute positioning.  I think my problem is using the absolute tag.  With in VS2010 my Master.Site page has a JPG that is image mapped.  I have placed Div's with absolute positioning over the top of this in all the pages that inherit from this.  With in VS2010 designer the div's do not appear to be on the page, but when i run it locally it looks fine.  When I put it up on the IIS server it looks fine, on my machine.  On Mac's and older PC's they are off the amount that they are off in the designer.  Why don't I see it the same?  If I make it look right in the designer then it looks wrong on My machine.

```
 `<div style="position: absolute; top: 321px; left: 900px; height: 427px; width: 602px; z-index: auto; float: none;`
```

you can see this at www.cbfnet.com/test3

Comment: Have you tried a percentage value? 900px is 900px regardless of resolution size.  So a screen that's 1024 x 768 will only see a piece of it while 1600 x 1200 will probably see the whole thing.  Depending on your page layout, percentages can change based on screen resolution.  Just a thought, and I could be wrong, so not an answer :)

Comment: What is the exact look that you are trying to achieve? Do you really want to have the text fixed 900 pixels from the left side of the window, while the slient side map is centered? This looks awkward when changing the window size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a position:relative on the parent div. Add that style to your .main class, then re-adjust your 'left:' value.

Comment: I don't understand?  I don't think I have a Parent Div or are you talking about his one in the master Site?  <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

Comment: Yea, sorry I was looking at your link you provided. The div with class="main"; give .main a position:relative then redo the left: value of the div you posted above - probably want to make it something like left:390px; if you want it to be in the white area. Hope that helps!

Comment: That was it thank you, I had to go back to the master.site and add that to the Div class=main.